# What's the performance implication of chaining assignment

Tags: c++, c

I have 2 `Reset()` functions. Are there any performance implications of [2] when compared to [1]?

[1]

```
void Reset(){
  _a = 0;
  _b = 0;
  _c = 0;
  _d = 0;
}
```

[2]

```
void Reset(){
  _a = _b = _c = _d = 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly no difference, with a halfway sane compiler.  But ultimately it depends on a lot of things.  What type, what hardware, etc.

Comment: @Kenny Lim For the both functions the compiler can generate the same object code.:)

Comment: _@Kenny Lim_ Measure 1st, then ask about doubtful stuff!

Answer (score 4):

As always, when things matter you should test them empirically rather than relying solely on theoretical reasoning.

In this case, however, I would imagine that the two code snippets become *identical* after compilation, so there is no difference.

... at least in the typical case. If, for example, your variables are of a type that has the property that

- it is cheap to assign an integer value to it
- it is expensive to copy from another instance of that type

then you would expect chained assignment to be much more expensive, unless the optimizer is sufficiently clever.

(and the reverse if it's expensive to assign an integer but cheap to copy assign)